# new H.data.geojson.Reader giving me an error of undefined. HERE maps

Tags: javascript, json, here-maps-rest

I am new to **here maps**. I want to render my data using routing API results on the map.
I am using the code from the documentation but I am getting an error **H.data is not defined**.

Code I am using.

```
 var reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader('/ajax/pull_map_here.php');
    reader.parse();//Assumption:mapalreadyexists

    map.addLayer(reader.getLayer());
```

I am using these scripts. Do I need to add any other script to resolve this error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geojson/0.5.0/geojson.min.js"></script>
```

Initializing the platform object

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': 'APIKEY_HERE',
        'useHTTPS': true

    });
```

Anyone who can help me out. Much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Might be problem with http/https script serving.maybe 'useHTTPS': true when initializing the platform object

Comment: @SachinYadav Thanks for your response but it's not working. Please check the updated question. I am adding the platform object as well in question.

Comment: Hint:- H.data is not able to fetch the data, I think now you would understand what is the problem

Comment: I am giving the right data but still the same issue. I parsed the full response and the tried waypoints object as well but still the same issue.

Comment: Did it work for you

Comment: @SachinYadav. No did not work. Do you have any other idea or suggestion?

Comment: Don't pass .php as a parameter in reader you need to put json in that it's clearly mentioned on here maps documentation site

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-data.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Provides H.data